# IPA Download very Slow

Tags: ios, performance, adhoc, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

Im downloading IPA file from iPad for AdHoc distribution but download so slow that can't end the download and show an error. I download other files from that server and the velocity it's ok, it seem be a problem with IPA files. I put the file in other server and the same problem.